# os.path.join giving incorrect result

Tags: python

I am trying to join a plf path to build location using the below code but i notice that  the plf name is being overwritten on the build location ,please see below fore details,what am I missing here?

```
rPlf = os.path.join(buildLocation,'au_connect_build.plf')
    print rPlf
    print rPlf
```

Actual output:-

```
rPlf
\au_connect_build.plfNTEGRATION\M1234BAAAANAA120080.1
```

Expected output:-

```
 \\Location\builds435\INTEGRATION\M1234BAAAANAA120080.1\au_connect_build.plf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buildLocation` contains an `\r` character - run `print repr(rPlf)` and you'll see what is happening. You can fix that with:

```
buildLocation = buildLocation.strip('\r')
```